# Representation of Bosonic Hopping Operator in Bargmann space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, bosons, bose-hubbard-model

In the [Segal-Bargmann representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%E2%80%93Bargmann_space), the bosonic canonical operators can be mapped to differential operators via $a\to z$ and $a^\dagger \to \partial_z$ such that the number operator can be written as $N=\sum_i z_i \partial_{z_i}$.

The nearest neighboring hopping operator of say Bose-Hubbard model takes the form $a^\dagger_j a_{j+1}+a^\dagger_{j+1}a_j$ which in the first quantized form can be thought at a discrete version of Laplace operator acting on the wvefunction.

In the Bargman representation, it seems to take a very complicated form $z_j\partial_{z_{j+1}}+z_{j+1}\partial_{z_j}$. Are there any other tricks to represent it?

Comment: This complicated form is exactly what you want, though. See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution#Time_evolution_and_operator_correspondences

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why this is *complicated*.  For example there is an obvious single particle eigenfunction of
$$
H = \sum_n (z_{n+1}\partial_n + z_n \partial_{n+1})
$$
given by
$$
\psi(\ldots z_{-1},z_0, z_1,z_2,\dots)= \sum_{n} z_n e^{ikn}.
$$
with energy $2\cos k$. Mutiple occupancy of such states can be obtained by considering symmetric polynomials in the $z_n$.

BTW I think you mean the Bargmann representation.  Both Bergman and Bargmann have Hilbert spaces of holomorphic functions, but they are different people and quite different spaces.

Comment: I am kind of confused by the notation.  $\partial_n$ you wrote is $\frac{d}{dz_n}$, right?

So, when with $\psi=\sum_m z_m e^{ikm}$ and $H\psi= \sum_n(z_{n+1}\partial_n+z_n \partial_{n+1}) \sum_m z_m e^{ikm}=\sum_n\sum_m z_{n+1}\delta_{n,m}e^{ikn}+z_n \delta_{n+1,m}e^{ikm}$? I am not sure what I am missing here

Comment: $\sum_{m,n} (\delta_{nm} z_{n+1}+ z_n \delta_{n+1,m})e^{ikm}= (e^{ik} +e^{-ik}) \sum_n z_n e^{ikn}$

Comment: I see. so this only works when n goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ but not for a finite number of sites.